# Trouble understanding tweepy pagination

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter, tweepy

I want to use search terms in the Twitter API between 2 dates which may return 1000s of results. Is this even possible in the free version? I’m using tweepy and unsure if I should be using pages or not. When I set ‘count’ to any number I always get the same number of results back. I have set count=100 and got over 900 results in my latest test. How can I count the number of results returned? I have done lots of googling but can’t find the answer to this simple question. It’s basic stuff I know, but I find the Twitter documentation as clear as mud and the tweepy documentation not simple enough for a newbie. I want to store the results in an SQLite database for doing analysis. I’m happy with the database but don’t understand the pagination in tweepy. The documentation uses api.friends. I want to use api.search. I want to retrieve the maximum number of results possible.

Any help hugely appreciated!

Basically the bit I'm not understanding is how to return the maximum number of tweets using code like:

```
    tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                   q=search_words,
                   lang='en',
                   since=date_since,
                   count=200).items()
    db.add_tweets(tweets)
```

This returns more than 200 tweets. Is it returning all the tweets or will I hit a 3200 limit? Is it saying there are 200 tweets per page? Some of the examples in the tweeps docs use pages(). I don't understand pagination! How do I find the number of tweets in each page if there's not 200? How do I know how many tweets have been returned from the query without doing count on the database? How would I iterate over every page if I use pages()? I apologise for my lack of understanding but the documentation is definitely not for newbies! Please can someone help? Thanks

Comment: can you share your code? what are you actually doing in your program?

Comment: I updated the question Andy. I just need advice on the best way to search the api! Can you help? Thanks.